# Styling the Bootstrap mobile menu on navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove the outline and background color form mobile-menu[Hamburger menu].I only want the horizontal 3 line without outline and background color.

Here is what i'm trying but it's still showing the outline when not hover/focused.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container">
                 <div class="navbar-header">
                         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         </button>
                         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">abc</a>
                 </div>

                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                 <li>
                                         <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                                 </li>
                         </ul>
                 </div>
         </div>
 </nav>
```

And this is css i'm applying

```
 .navbar-default{
    background-color: #862f38;
}
.navbar-toggle:link,
.navbar-toggle:visited,
.navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-toggle:active,
.navbar-toggle:focus{
  background:none !important;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.navbar-toggle:link,
.navbar-toggle:visited,
.navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-toggle:active,
.navbar-toggle:focus{
  background:none !important;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

But i don't know why it's not working.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Whts wrong in my code???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below simple code

---

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle{
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this code, this will give only three horizontal lines, This works fine for me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.navbar{
background:#ddd;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: may be because of you use .navbar-inverse class

Comment: If there is a navbar-inverse class it works fine!!! If no narbar-inverse class u can simply remove that from css right???

Comment: yes.. i saw in my answer with element inspect there is no navbar-inverse class use that's why may be you are downvoted because of that.

Comment: now  i updated my fiddle, just take a look there, in my example i have navbar-inverse class

Answer (score 1):

You need to add css to `.navbar-toggle`

```css
.navbar-default{
    background-color: #862f38;
}
.navbar-toggle:link,
.navbar-toggle:visited,
.navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-toggle:active,
.navbar-toggle:focus{
  background:none !important;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.navbar-toggle:link,
.navbar-toggle:visited,
.navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-toggle:active,
.navbar-toggle:focus{
  background:none !important;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
  .navbar-toggle{
    border:none !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container">
                 <div class="navbar-header">
                         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         </button>
                         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">abc</a>
                 </div>

                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                 <li>
                                         <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                                 </li>
                         </ul>
                 </div>
         </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this?

```css
 .navbar-default{
    background-color: #862f38;
}
.navbar-toggle:link,
.navbar-toggle:visited,
.navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-toggle:active,
.navbar-toggle:focus{
  background:none !important;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.navbar-toggle:link,
.navbar-toggle:visited,
.navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-toggle:active,
.navbar-toggle:focus{
  background:none !important;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
 
}
   .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent !important;
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container">
                 <div class="navbar-header">
                         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         </button>
                         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">abc</a>
                 </div>

                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                 <li>
                                         <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                                 </li>
                         </ul>
                 </div>
         </div>
 </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just add css in `navbar-toggle`:

```
.navbar-toggle{
  border:none;
  background:none;
}
```

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q0uxe6t0/